# PHP function unserialize stop working after charset change (from latin1 to UTF-8)

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, utf-8, latin1

I use the PHP function serialize to serialize an object with a big string, in the string are a special character "—". That object was save when the DB was using latin1 charset now I migrate the db to UTF-8.

I use the PHP function unserialize to get the object back, since I changed the charset to UTF-8 that function stop working. I don't know why.

I modify httpd.conf to use:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .utf8
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

php.ini:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

And CONVERT all MySQL data to UTF-8.

**UPDATE**
I catch the php error when I call the unserialize function:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 19146 of 23672 bytes in /xxx/xxx.php:18
```

Comment: Perform `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` to show us the hex for the naughty character.  That will help decide whether the data is wrong in the database or the data is being processed incorrectly after fetching from the database.

Comment: The HEX is E28094, thanks Rick.

Comment: Looks that it is an UTF-8 character (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm), so the mysql side is correct, and the problem is in apache/php?

Comment: Do you have <meta...utf8> in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the length of the serialized string was wrong after change from latin1 to UTF-8.
I fix the problem using this PHP:

```
$content = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $content);
```

I'm going to update the data base with the new string.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use json_encode/decode instead of un/serialize?

Comment: Note that this won't work if the serialized string contains the substring `";`

Answer (score 1):

Now, please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` and show the results.

If the CHARACTER SET of the column you stored E28094 into was latin1, you have a mess.  It needed to be converted to hex 97, the latin1 encoding for EM-dash, but was not.  Probably you had utf8 bytes, but (by default) told MySQL you had utf8 bytes.  It may read as "â€”" -- the latin1 decoding of each byte.  This is because the MySQL thinks of it as 3 latin1 characters.  [Here is the *likely* solution.](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixing_utf8_bytes_in_latin1_column)  But, be cautious.

If the CHARACTER SET of the column was utf8, then all is well in the table.

The long-winded discussion of problems like this is in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll) .

Comment: -The column is longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
-The table is ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci" 

Before was latin1.

Comment: I use this query to migrate from latin1 to UTF-8:
ALTER DATABASE <DB> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

Comment: Does the EM-dash print correctly?  Does the HEX still say E28094?

Comment: The EM-dash is in a longtext column with a serialised string. When I show the content of that column using PHP it is show correctly.
The problem is when I use the content in unserialize function (I just update the question with new info I get debugging the PHP).

Comment: Hmmm... I did serialize(), then unserialize(); E28094 was returned intact.  Did you write the serialized string to a file or MySQL?  If so, could you do the same actions with just "—".  If that fails, we might have a way to get a better handle on _what_ is going wrong and _what_ is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We converted our project from WINDOWS-1251 (cyrillic) to UTF-8 and this function is great help to us:

```
function mb_unserialize($string) {
    $string = preg_replace_callback('/s:(\d+):"(.*?)";/', function($matches) {
        return 's:'.strlen($matches[2]).':"'.$matches[2].'";';
    },
     $string);
    return unserialize($string);
}
```

For example, strlen('Минск') == 5 when WINDOWS-1251 is the default server encoding and strlen('Минск') == 10 when it is UTF-8.
In our DB we still keep data serialized by the old system, so the mb_unserialize function is an easy way to get the result.